# jQuery .on('click', ...) with a selector not registering middle clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery .on() with a selector is not firing on middle clicks. But it does if the on() method doesn't have a selector or if attaching the event directly to the element. How can I get attach an event handler to capture all clicks on any child elements?

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/trzyhc73/3/**

```
$("body").on("click", "button", function(event) {
    alert("Mouse button " + event.which);
});
// Doesn't register middle click events


$("body").on("click", function(event) {
    alert("Mouse button " + event.which);
});
// Does register middle click events!
```

Comment: Your example (jsFiddle) is not using .on

Comment: This is a wont-fix from a couple of years ago - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11485 I dunno if they've changed their opinion on it, but this has happened for quite a while.

Comment: Apologies, pasted the wrong link. Correct jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jordn/trzyhc73/1/

Comment: Please don't use `alert`... it makes debugging really really really annoying. Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/trzyhc73/3/

Comment: Great thanks Joe - would upvote if I could. Thanks Mottie and Jonas92, I've improved the jsfiddle on your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("body").on("mousedown", "button", function (event) {
    alert("Mouse button " + event.which);
});
```

Comment: Accepted this as the 'good enough' solution for now. @Joe has pointed out this is a won't-fix from a couple of years ago http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11485

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

```
$("body").mousedown(function(e){
    switch(e.which)
    {
        case 1: //left Click 
        break;
        case 2: //middle Click 
        break;
        case 3: //right Click 
        break;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: >.< Everyone is upvoting an answer that has nothing to do with the question